# Create a wave animation with SVG and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to animate a path with SVG creating a similar effect as show below:
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Animations_of_vibrations_and_waves#/media/File:Amfm2.gif

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Animations_of_vibrations_and_waves#/media/File:Frontgroupphase.gif

The problem is that I have never used SVG to create a path transformation and I don't know if it's even possible to achieve this result. Looking through the web I have found [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) but still no clear documentation. Are there any examples available or even a working demo of such a thing?

Comment: You need to add more information and show what you've tried so far. Its not clear what the data for the wave would be based on for example. You could also take a look at d3.js if changing datasets is fundamental to it.

Comment: @Ian: I have not tried to add data or any points. I am just exploring my options if I would be able to recreate a similar animation.

Comment: Yes, you would be able to create similar, it may come down to how fluid/fast you want it to move, and the complexity etc, as to whether its the right solution. I would look into d3.js if data based, Snap may be fine if you want to roll your own. If you need performance without interactivity you may want to look at a Canvas lib. It also depends if its a one off animation or you want it to vary depending on other things happening on the screen or something.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an `<animate>` element to animate the `d` attribute of a path. See http://codepen.io/noahblon/blog/an-intro-to-svg-animation-with-smil

Comment: You [probably shouldn't try animating an element with SMIL, though](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5371475380928512).